# Write classification to raster for highest object in LiDAR point cloud

Tags: lidar, pdal

What we want to do is rasterize the classification value of the **highest** point (in the `Z` dimension) in every pixel. Basically we are trying to mimic optical imagery where whatever is on top is what is seen.

So if we naively use `pdal`:

```
{
                    "type": "writers.gdal",
                    "filename": "classification.tif",
                    "dimension": "Classification",
                    "output_type": "max",
                    "binmode": "true",
                    "resolution": 2.0,
}
```

then every pixel will have the value of the maximum **class label** written to it, not the classification value of the highest point. So if high vegetation has class `5` but a `Z=16.5` and buildings have class `6` but `Z=12.0`, then a pixel will take the value of class `6`, even if the high vegetation is "above" the buildings.

What we want is to take the point with the highest `Z` value in each pixel, but write the classification value to a raster.
So take the `max` of `Z`, but write classification.

This seems like it should be straightforward to do, but I don't see a way to do so in `pdal` without rewriting `writers.gdal`.

If anyone has any suggestions, or know of any packages in which this will be easier to do, please let us know.